# Why does pytest factory as fixture provide persistent object instance?

Tags: python, pytest

I have this test class I run with pytest:

Edit: added PhoneBook class definition. That's pretty much all there is.

```
from typing import Dict, Callable

import pytest


class PhoneBook:
    numbers: Dict[str, str] = {}

    def add(self, name: str, number: str) -> None:
        self.numbers[name] = number

    def lookup(self, name: str) -> str:
        return self.numbers[name]
        # pass

    def names(self):
        return set(self.numbers.keys())


@pytest.fixture
def phonebook_provider() -> Callable[[], PhoneBook]:
    def _get_phone_book():
        return PhoneBook()

    return _get_phone_book


def test_phonebook_by_name(phonebook_provider):
    phonebook_provider().add("Bob", "1234")
    assert phonebook_provider().lookup("Bob") == "1234"
```

I believe it should get fresh (and thus empty) instance upon each call. Therefore the test should fail. But it passes.

Why? Is there an implicit closure or something?

Comment: I suspect it's more a question of how `PhoneBook` is defined.

Comment: I tried reproducing it with my own implementation of `PhoneBook` based on what you provided, and the assertion fails as expected.  It seems your `PhoneBook` class is behaving as a singleton somehow.  Did you use a `dict` as a default argument to a function, or maybe a class attribute?

Comment: change to `numbers: Dict[str, str]`

    `def __init__(self):
     self.numbers = {}`

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, this worked. But why? It feels like a static field in java. But is it? Which part of documentation should I read?